# How to insert data using values from a scalar variables in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I need to insert data in a table using values returned from a cursor. I am actually capturing the values into a scalar variable and Now I need to insert data into another table using the values in variable. Since the variable carries two values I am not sure how to insert data using those values one by one.

Following pic shows the value

[image]

@tran_id variable carries above highlighted value and I need to insert data into another table using these value. So in where clause it would be like where id = 24163 then 24164 but how to get them one by one is putting me in stress.

SP

```
-- Inserting into main table
    INSERT INTO ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION
    VALUES (2, 1001, 'axaa1aaa-aaaa-a5aa-aaaa-aa8aaaa9aaaa', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, getDate(), 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 'SYSTEM', getDate(), NULL, getDate());

    INSERT INTO ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION
    VALUES (2, 1001, 'bxbb1bbb-bbbb-b5bb-bbb4-bb8bbbb9bbbf', NULL, NULL, NULL, 1, getDate(), 0, NULL, 0, NULL, 'SYSTEM', getDate(), NULL, getDate());

    DECLARE @tran_id INT;   
    DECLARE @identifier VARCHAR(100);

    DECLARE tran_cursor CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID, IDENTIFIER FROM ESG.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION 
    WHERE IDENTIFIER IN('axaa1aaa-aaaa-a5aa-aaaa-aa8aaaa9aaaa','bxbb1bbb-bbbb-b5bb-bbb4-bb8bbbb9bbbf' );

    OPEN tran_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM tran_cursor INTO @tran_id, @identifier;

    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
       PRINT 'Tran_ID = ' + CAST(@tran_id AS VARCHAR(100)) + ' Identifier = ' + @identifier     
       FETCH NEXT FROM tran_cursor INTO @tran_id, @identifier;                                        
    END

    CLOSE tran_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE tran_cursor;
```

Insert statement

```
INSERT INTO esg.DOCUMENT_SET_TRANS_MDATA (DOCUMENT_SET_TRANSACTION_ID, MDATA_ATTRB, MDATA_VALUE, CREATED_TIME, LAST_MOD_TIME, ISACTIVE) 
VALUES (@tran_id, 'SOURCE', 'M1', getDate(), getDate(), 1);
```

This is inserting same set of data for both ids highlighted above. Here I need to make a distinction so that I insert different set of data for both ids.

Comment: Sounds like you want a table variable. Why is this a cursor though?

Comment: The cursor lets you iterate through a data set one row at a time. Inside the `WHILE` loop the variables hold the values of the row that was last read. Overall though, what @JacobH said. Why are you using a cursor when you can do the insert as a set operation, which is what relational databases are good at.

Comment: I am performing some more operations too that is why it is a cursor. I am able to insert data but for both ids in highlighted I can insert same data set because I cannot differentiate between.

Comment: If I could get the two ids separately and then do the insert upon would solve my issue.

Comment: You are already FETCHing the `IDENTIFIER` value into `@identifier` so can't you use that in an IF construct to control what you INSERT as you loop through the cursor?

Comment: So I need to insert based on the @tran_id which changes every time this SP executes. So I can't really say if this is (1234) do this because the id would be different next time I run this.

Comment: My point was that even if you can't make a decision based on the value of `@tran_id` you *might* be able to make a decision based on the value of `@identifier`, since that is a value that you supplied yourself when you created the rows to which the `@tran_id` values were assigned. If that's not the case then please [edit] your question to better explain what you really need to accomplish.

Comment: The whole point of these identifiers is to get ids. I know these identifiers are static but not the ids. And this is SQL Server ids act as FK ans that's the only way to insert into other tables.